# How to avoid ridiculously salty results when brining?  

Tags: barbecue, ribs, brining

Last time I brined, the ribs came out ridiculously salty.  Can someone provide me with a good brining method?

Comment: Add less salt. 

And in general, this site isn't supposed to be a recipe exchange.

Comment: Really? Why not?  Doesn't seem to say that in the FAQs...

Comment: See: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/255/why-is-recipe-swapping-a-bad-thing

Comment: Providing the recipe that you used would also be helpful, Abe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical brine is 5% salt by weight. You are then left with the question of how long to leave the meat in the brine. In the case of pork ribs, they're little and need less time than say a whole chicken or a turkey. I'd suggest you go short, like 4 to 6 hours to start.

Answer (score 5):

Did you rinse the ribs well enough before cooking? Brined food should be rinsed several times to remove brining solids from the surface of the food before cooking.